# Impossible to find socket of MySQL (MariaDB installed)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following error, but when I try to find the socket file there is in fact nothing

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

I have MariaDB on a Ubuntu 18.04.
How can I add this socket? I used to work with MySQL but I am a bit lost with MariaDB as they replicated config everywhere.

**EDIT 1**

nothing related to mysql / mariadb here:

> /var/run/mysqld

```
nicolas@nicolas-UX530UX:/var/run$ ls /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
ls: cannot access '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock': No such file or directory

nicolas@nicolas-UX530UX:/var/run$ service mysql status
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
```

Comment: ok I found my mistake, I had installed only mariadb-client and not server! sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

Make sure that you have installed the `mysql-server`, not the `mysql-client` or something else. If you didn't install `mysql-server`, then the file would not exist. So install `mysql-server`.

### Solution 2

If the `mysql-server` is already installed and is running, then you need to check the config files.

The config files are located at:

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf
```

In `/etc/my.cnf`, the socket file config may be `/tmp/mysql.sock`

and

in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` the socket file config may be `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

So, remove or rename `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, and let mysql use as `/etc/my.cnf`.

Comment: `grep -rin socket /etc/mariadb /etc/mysql`